# Find consecutive numbers in Excel

Tags: excel

Question:
if I have a column of data showing 010110111001111000

1=breach and 0=non-breach

Find the total number of consecutive breaches, for example '11' implies 1 consecutive breaches and '111'implies 2 consecutive breaches

By inspection, total number of consecutive breaches = 6

Is there a formula in Excel that can solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTIFS with offset ranges:

```
 =COUNTIFS(A1:A17,1,A2:A18,1)
```

Note the two ranges are offset one row from each other, so it counts where there are two `1`s together.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

- 2nd '1' is a breach, so replace the 1st '1' as '0'
- let the very beginning always as '0'.
- removing all '0's
- count the length.

[image]

Combining the formula:

`=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A7,"01","00"),1,1,0),0,""))`

Comment: Changing the first value to `0` may impact the result. If the first 3 entries were `1` for instance. Better add a `0` prior to the range and than substitute like you said: `=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("0"&A7,"01","00"),0,""))`

Comment: I don't think that make a difference

Comment: You're right. I thought you replaced the first character with `0` and then substituted `01` for `00` hence my comment. This is not the case though. It works fine.