# Identifying a period of time unsold - how do I return the invoice number after a specified period of time without an invoice?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We've defined new accounts as accounts that purchase something after at least 90 days without any purchases. I've plotted out the data in a table showing months and the first invoice that occurred in that month.

I've used the COUNTIFS formula [suggested in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68653120/find-consecutive-numbers-in-excel) to identify accounts that qualify as "new accounts". Right now, I have the formula returning "New" or "Current".

What I really need is to return the invoice number that occurred after 90 days unsold.

So in the attached example, Account A was unsold from May-July, then purchased invoice 133871 in August. How would I get it to return "133871" in Column1 instead of "New"? For Account B, I would need it to return March's invoice of 125884.

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

[image]

Comment: So, you can find the row with the matching criteria now use index() to return the result from column 1. However, you may want to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700 give it a vote if it helps.

Comment: Theoretically, you could have 3 times in a year for the same account, what do you do with those?

Comment: @scottcraner I would prefer the newest result. Thank you for the help.

Comment: use MAXIFS with 4 ranges: `=MAXIFS(jan-aug,oct-may,"",nov-jun,"",dec-jul,"")`

Comment: @scottcraner this is brilliant, thank you. If you make it an Answer, I'll accept it.